# Python, how to set index properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, indexing

I have a question for you.

I have the following code:

```
defaults = list(0 for m in range(12))
index=6
totale=5
for i in index:
    defaults[i]=totale
```

But give me error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. I want to set the value totale for each month starting from the index untill the end of the year, but the `[index:]` does not works. 
In other words I want to obtain the following result:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
```

Comment: "But give me error" - what error? Also, please post a [mcve].

Comment: I have added the example and the error description

Comment: Please edit the __full__ error message into your question, so that, for example, someone reading could work out which line the errotr occurs at. and please edit the code in your question to be a [mre] - I should be able to paste the code into a file and _without adding anything_ run it to see the error you are seeing.

Comment: I have changed my answer following your suggestions. Now follow the principles that you have said to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
for i in range(index, 12):
    defaults[i]=totale
```

Comment: @Jfix91 - Your desired result shows a list in which the 6th item an onward are set to 5, while this answer will start the 5s at the 7th element (element at position 6). Which is your desired result - the one in this answer, or the one in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what the variable types are, but you can use a simple for loop

```
index=month
for i in index:
    fondo_immobbilizzazioni_mat[tipologia][i] = totale
```

Note, it'll only work if month is of type list/array.

Comment: give me also the same error: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

Given the values of `index` and `totale`, all you need to do is the following:

```
defaults = [0] * index + [totale] * (12 - index)
```

Another option, slightly more complex to read, but (possibly) marginally more memory-effective, since it would not create any temporary lists, would be:

```
defaults = [0 if i < index else totale for i in range(12)]
```

It really does not matter much which you use, as long as this line is not called an excessive number of times.